# What does 'MSP' stand for in the context of Chinese parts of speech?

Tags: computational-linguistics, parts-of-speech, chinese, particles, pos-tagging

The Part-Of-Speech Tagging Guidelines for the PennChineseTreebank(3.0) uses several acronyms without defining them. I am a hobbyist student of Chinese linguistics as part of my study of Chinese.

I cannot figure out what MSP stands for. They say that MSPs include 所，以，而，＆ 来。 From the examples given, I think P stands for particle, S may stand for structural or sentence, and M might stand for medial. Other than P, these are just my guesses.

I would love any help.

[image: screenshot from the pdf, linked below]

[image: second screenshot from the pdf, linked below]

https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~clp/ctb/posguide.3rd.ch.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I emailed Fei Xia and she said that MSP simply means **miscallenous particles**. I don't think it actually means anything more special, like "modal structural particle," or otherwise.

[image]

Page 17 of the attached file is what you put on the question already.